# pngcrush causing black background on some images

Tags: php, png, pngcrush

I'm using the following to optimize some png images with pngcrush:

```
exec(
    "pngcrush -q -blacken -brute -reduce -rem alla -rem text -rem time {$source} {$destination}",
    $output,
    $return_var
);
```

The optimization works really well, but for some images, the png is creating these black blocks where the transparency goes.

The problem goes away when I remove the -reduce option, but then the PNG optimization does very little, and it's no use at all running the optimization.

I'm assuming that the problem is to do with transparency, so is there a way to tell pngcrush, to skip the -reduce command, only for images that don't have transparency?

Comment: I think is due to MIME type of your png image.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a source image that exhibits the behavior?  Also, what version of pngcrush are you using?  The current version is 1.7.70.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `-blacken`, as it is the immediate cause of your problem.

From [the changelog](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/changelog.html):

> Added -blacken option, to enable changing the color samples of any
>       fully-transparent pixels to zero in PNG files with color-type 4 or 6,
>       potentially improving their compressibility. Note that this is an
>       irreversible lossy change: the underlying colors of all fully transparent
>       pixels are lost, if they were not already black.

Possibly some of your transparent pixels are not as transparent as they seem.

Comment: I tried removing blacken, but it was infact only when i removed -reduce when the problem went away, but then I have practically no optimization. The solution I used was to check if the images contain alpha before I save them, and if they don't I just save as a jpeg image.

Comment: Interesting -- thanks for the follow-up. Can you still provide a link to a file that shows this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on v1.7.65 with just the "-reduce" option. The same image and command worked fine on v1.7.86.